# React: Rendering Extra Components in Array Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, socket.io

I'm a student and new to react.  I'm creating a mind-tree with components rendering out of arrays, that will eventually have children of their own.  I ran into this problem where an additional  duplicate child (of the first child) is rendered.  It's only happens after three, and never becomes part of the data structure itself.  I wasn't able to find many similar problems posted, if you have any ideas they would be very appreciated!

```
displayChildren = () => {
        let num = 1;
        let childs = [];
        if(this.props.Data.Children == null)
            return;

        this.props.Data.Children.map(idea => { 
            childs.push(
                <td key = {'R-'+this.props.Data.Children.length}>
                    <Idea key={'I-'+this.props.Data.Children.length} Data={idea} pushToTop={this.pushToTop}/>
                </td>
            );
            console.log("Creating Child >"+ num++ +"< for "+this.props.Data.Title, childs);
        });

        console.log("FINISHED CHILDREN: ", childs);
        return(<tr align="center" valign="top">{childs}</tr>);
    }Picture: Two Children -> Working
```

[image]

Picture: Two Children Log -> Two children in data.

[image]

Picture: Three Children -> Error, duplicate render -> Four Children Displayed

Note: The connections are based off the size of array, which is three, hence only displaying three.

[image]

Picture: Three Children Log -> Three Children in Data

[image]

Additional Note: I eventually want to have multiple users and plan to use Socket.IO to pass current Data back and forth by replacing the head/origin of the tree.  With Sockets it render's extra components to the power of users, and then crashes the browser soon after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's significant room for improvement in your code. I'll start by reworking it, then explain the reasoning behind some of the changes.

```
displayChildren = () => {
  if (!Array.isArray(this.props.Data.Children)) return;

  const childs = this.props.Data.Children.map((idea, i) => {
    console.log(`Creating Child >${i}< for ${this.props.Data.Title}`, this.props.Data.Children);
    return (
      <td key = {`R-${idea.Title}`}>
        <Idea Data={idea} pushToTop={this.pushToTop}/>
      </td>
    );
  });

  console.log("FINISHED CHILDREN: ", childs);
  return(<tr align="center" valign="top">{childs}</tr>);
}
```

If the above code solves the problem, the main issue was that you were using the same key for all `<td>`s, because `this.props.Data.Children.length` will always be the same - it doesn't change as you `map` through each element in the array.

Instead, I used `idea.Title` to build a (hopefully) unique key for each `<td>`. You could also use `i` (short for `index`, the second argument provided to the callback function by `map`, which I also used in the inner `console.log` statement), but that can be problematic in some situations (e.g. if you are adding, removing or sorting elements in the`this.props.Data.Children` array dynamically).

Other improvements:

Don't create an array then `push` to it inside `map`. Mapping over an array returns a new array, anyway, so there's no need to push to a separate array.

[Prefer string literal syntax to string concatenation with the `+` symbol.](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/template-literals-strictly-better-strings)

`Idea` doesn't need a unique key here. Only the `<td>`s do.

Rather than checking whether `this.props.Data.Children` is equal to `null` before trying to `map` over it, I checked whether it was an Array. This is safer, in case you accidentally set `this.props.Data.Children` to something other than `null` or an Array.

There's room for more improvement, but it's outside of the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` must be unique, which is not the case in your code. Non-unique keys can cause weird behavior like you got. Please generate a unique key for each `<td>` in your loop, and it will fix your problem.

```
<td key = {'R-'+this.props.Data.Children.length}>
```